# Concise way to check an array of objects for a key/value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

What would be a short and concise way to find if each of the strings in the array below exists for some id in an object in the array? I know I could perform a for loop, but if I'm running multiple lookups it becomes tedious.

**The below example should output false because one matches, one doesn't.**

```
var array1= [
'j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n',
'ln23jk4n2njknn2n'
]


var array2 = [
    {
        fruit:"banana"
        origin:"florida"
        id:"j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n"
    },
    {
        fruit:"peach"
        origin:"georgia"
        id:"l2nkj2n3k4bj"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code outputs a boolean. true if all ids are available in array2

```js
var array1 = [
  'j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n',
  "l2nkj2n3k4bj",
  'ln23jk4n2njknn2n'
]


var array2 = [{
    fruit: "banana",
    origin: "florida",
    id: "j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n",
  },
  {
    fruit: "peach",
    origin: "georgia",
    id: "l2nkj2n3k4bj"
  },
]

const results = array1.every(id => array2.find(item => item.id === id))

console.log(results)
```

If you want to find which element is found/not found, use the below method. It outputs an array with boolean values and has the same count as `array1`. If an `id` is found the output array will have `true` in that array position.

```js
var array1 = [
  'j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n',
  "l2nkj2n3k4bj",
  'ln23jk4n2njknn2n'
]


var array2 = [{
    fruit: "banana",
    origin: "florida",
    id: "j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n",
  },
  {
    fruit: "peach",
    origin: "georgia",
    id: "l2nkj2n3k4bj"
  },
]
// Initial approach which works
// const results = array1.map(id => Boolean(array2.find(item => item.id === id)));

// Another approached as suggested by VLAZ and Phong in comments.  `some` will check and return the boolean.

const results = array1.map(id => array2.some(item => item.id === id));

console.log(results)
```

Comment: Why `Boolean(array2.find(item => item.id === id))`? It's just equivalent to `array2.some(item => item.id === id)`

Comment: Boolean is not required. Removed , initially I used a different approach.

Comment: Why don't you use `array2.some(item => item.id === id)` instead of `Boolean(array2.find(item => item.id === id))`? @kiranvj

Comment: @Phong we can use `some` and will be a better choice

Comment: Yeah, I do think so. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Destructuring.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const array1 = ["j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n", "ln23jk4n2njknn2n"],
  array2 = [
    {
      fruit: "banana",
      origin: "florida",
      id: "j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n",
    },
    {
      fruit: "peach",
      origin: "georgia",
      id: "l2nkj2n3k4bj",
    },
  ];

const result = array1.every((id1) => array2.some(({ id }) => id === id1));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can also convert `array1` to an instance of Set to reduce the complexity from `O(M x N)` to `O(N)`.

Comment: I removed the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.idexOf` or more elegant `Array.prototype.includes`

```js
let array1 = [
  'j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n',
  "l2nkj2n3k4bjx",
  'ln23jk4n2njknn2n'
]


let array2 = [{
    fruit: "banana",
    origin: "florida",
    id: "j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n",
  },
  {
    fruit: "peach",
    origin: "georgia",
    id: "l2nkj2n3k4bj"
  },
]

console.log("1st Approach");
array2.forEach(e => {
    if(array1.indexOf(e.id) < 0 ) console.log(false);
    else console.log(true);
});

console.log("2nd Approach");

array2.forEach(e => {
    if(array1.includes(e.id)) console.log(true);
    else console.log(false);
});
```

Comment: This is just wrong. It won't even run, let alone produce the correct result. Why are people upvoting it?

Comment: Hey, Nick and Phong sorry had a couple of typos and silly missouts. Fixed them here's the sample I tested it works fine. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: Readable code, but not good in terms of performance.

You can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) combined with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var array1 = ['j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n', 'ln23jk4n2njknn2n'];
var array2 = [{fruit: "banana", origin: "florida", id: "j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n"},
              {fruit: "peach",  origin: "georgia", id: "l2nkj2n3k4bj" }];

const checkIncludes = (a1, a2) => a1.every(s => a2.some(({id}) => s === id));

console.log(checkIncludes(array1, array2)); // false              --> Because one matches, one doesnt.
console.log(checkIncludes(["j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n"], array2)); // true --> Because one matches
```

### Solution 2: Better performance

You can convert the `array2` into `object` named `normalizedData`, then finding cost just takes `O(1)`

```js
var array1 = ['j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n', 'ln23jk4n2njknn2n'];
var array2 = [{fruit: "banana", origin: "florida", id: "j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n"},
              {fruit: "peach",  origin: "georgia", id: "l2nkj2n3k4bj" }];

const checkIncludes = (aString, aObject) => {
  const normalizedData = aObject.reduce((acc, {id}) => {
    acc[id] = id;
    return acc;
  },{});
  return aString.every(s => normalizedData[s]);
} 

console.log(checkIncludes(array1, array2)); // false              --> Because one matches, one doesnt.
console.log(checkIncludes(["j2n4k2j3n42k3j4n"], array2)); // true --> Because one matches
```